# Calculating time statistics over multiple lines based on field values

Tags: sql-server

I am facing a statistical calculation out of machine logs looking like this:

| Serial | TS | Command |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 61287 | 2020-09-16 14:03:52.000 | START |
| 61287 | 2020-09-16 14:05:16.000 | START |
| 61287 | 2020-09-16 17:15:23.000 | PAUSE |
| 61287 | 2021-02-16 11:18:16.000 | START |
| 61287 | 2021-02-16 11:18:26.000 | FINISH |
| 61287 | 2021-02-16 11:21:39.000 | START |
| 61287 | 2021-02-16 11:23:34.000 | START |
| 61287 | 2021-02-16 11:25:34.000 | FINISH |
| 61288 | 2021-02-18 18:10:53.000 | START |
| 61288 | 2021-02-18 18:12:04.000 | START |
| 61288 | 2021-02-18 18:14:02.000 | START |
| 61288 | 2021-02-18 18:15:25.000 | FINISH |

Logs structure cannot be changed. Target is calculating the overall working time upon every serial number. Commands are to be handled as a chronometer.

What is giving me headache is:

1. Commands can be repeated, repetitions must be ignored. Once the first START is given the chronometer stops at either the next PAUSE or the next FINISH.
2. Each Serial can be subject to more than one cycle (START to FINISH), the processing times must be summed.
3. Each PAUSE stops the chronometer until the next START is given.

I have been trying to think of a solution with partitioning, but I could not get over ignoring repeated commands. Having multiple cycles for most of Serials did not help either. I am now stuck in confusion.

---

Based on the received hints I worked out as follows, returning the wished data, not stylish though. Any further hint is welcome.

```sql
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE 
            WHEN Lines.PreviousCmd = 'START'  and Lines.Command = 'FINISH' THEN DATEDIFF(second, PreviousTS, TS)
            WHEN Lines.PreviousCmd = 'FINISH'  and Lines.Command = 'START' THEN 0
            WHEN Lines.PreviousCmd = 'START'  and Lines.Command = 'PAUSE' THEN DATEDIFF(second, PreviousTS, TS)
            WHEN Lines.PreviousCmd = 'PAUSE'  and Lines.Command = 'START' THEN 0
            WHEN Lines.PreviousCmd = 'PAUSE'  and Lines.Command = 'FINISH' THEN 0
            WHEN Lines.PreviousCmd = 'FINISH'  and Lines.Command = 'PAUSE' THEN 0
        ELSE 999999999999999999999999999999999999 END AS TimeOn
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                Serial,
                LAG(Serial, 1) OVER (ORDER BY Serial asc, TS asc ) as PreviousSerial,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Serial asc, TS asc) AS RN,
                LAG(TS, 1) OVER (ORDER BY Serial asc, TS asc ) as PreviousTS,
                TS,
                LAG(Command,1) OVER (ORDER BY Serial asc, TS asc ) AS PreviousCmd,
                Command
            FROM #tAPPLOGTMP
        ) Lines 
        where Command <> PreviousCmd
        and PreviousSerial = Serial
```

Comment: This could use a gaps-and-islands solution.

Comment: Thanks Stu, I am having a look to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your example data and turned it into reproduceable DML/DDL. Providing this makes it much easier for folks to answer your question.

```
DECLARE @Times TABLE (Serial BIGINT, TS DATETIME, Command NVARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @Times (Serial, TS, Command) VALUES
(61287,'2020-09-16 14:03:52.000', 'START '),
(61287,'2020-09-16 14:05:16.000', 'START '),
(61287,'2020-09-16 17:15:23.000', 'PAUSE '),  
(61287,'2021-02-16 11:18:16.000', 'START '),
(61287,'2021-02-16 11:18:26.000', 'FINISH'),
(61287,'2021-02-16 11:21:39.000', 'START '),
(61287,'2021-02-16 11:23:34.000', 'START '),
(61287,'2021-02-16 11:25:34.000', 'FINISH'),
(61288,'2021-02-18 18:10:53.000', 'START '),
(61288,'2021-02-18 18:12:04.000', 'START '),
(61288,'2021-02-18 18:14:02.000', 'START '),
(61288,'2021-02-18 18:15:25.000', 'FINISH');
```

Using that, I applied the windowed function LAG, which let's us look back a row, inside the window. Looking back at Command, we can determine which rows we want to use. That is wrapped in a subquery, because SQL Server is very picky about where you can use a windowed function.
Applying the filter that the last command shouldn't be the same as this command we can get rid of the duplicate rows. Using another LAG we can now look back at the previous TS, and do the math to determine the number of seconds that have elapsed. One more subquery wrap, and we can then SUM those second, for each serial.

| Serial | TotalSeconds |
| --- | --- |
| 61287 | 11736 |
| 61288 | 272 |

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Next time I will use DDL from the start.
By joining your useful hints to what I was working on I got to a solution: not the most stylish one for sure but working. I will update the question accordingly